# How to put 2 conditions in ngClass in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to put 2 conditions in my ngclass but it isn't working.

```
 <input type="password" [ngClass]="{active: submitted && !form.controls['password']}"  [formControl]="form.controls['password']" required>
   this.submitted = false;
 onSubmit(form: any) {
      this.submitted = true;
 }
```

Where my active is a class with border error and i am trying to show error on click.

Comment: change `active` to `'active'`

Comment: I cleared it by putting  [ngClass]="{active: submitted && !form.controls['password'].valid}" .I forgot valid.....

Comment: so it works without quotes?

Comment: yes Avinash....

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can try this !

Work nice for me !

```
ng-class=" {'active' : your condition, 'disabled' : your condition } "
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to decleare require inside the input tag if you using form control, you need to decleare it inside the ts file

HTML

```
<input type="password" [ngClass]="{'active': isActive()}"   [formControl]="form.controls['password']">
```

Typescript

```
constractor(fb : FormBuilder){
     this.submitted = false;
     this.form = fb.group({
        password: new FormControl({value: null}, Validators.compose([Validators.required]))
     });
}

onSubmit(form: any) {
      this.submitted = true;
}

isActive(){
   return this.submitted && !this.form.controls['password'];
}
```